# Add one second to yyyymmddhhmmss with awk

Tags: awk, time, replace

I have this file where the seventh field is a yyyymmddhhmmss. I need to increase just one second this number.

So far, I've come up with:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $7=$7+1 ' <file>
```

And it kinda works but... if the last two digits of the seventh field are "59", it obviously replaces with "60".

Is there any way to make awk aware that the field is a date, so I can increase just one second the whole column?

**Current file**

```
09099458|1|000|41181|0|0|20221130164738|67
82060649|1|000|36827|0|0|20221130172359|67
```

Expected result

```
09099458|1|000|41181|0|0|20221130164739|67
82060649|1|000|36827|0|0|20221130172400|67  <- From 17:23:59 to 17:24:00
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that while the program does what you want (except for the restriction you stated), it does even that only by chance. Also, please elaborate how far the "edge cases" are to be taken - do you ultimately want it to cope with the transition "20221231235959 to 20230101000000" correctly?

Comment: Wrong tool. Of course you can write a script to teach the second's overflow, minute overflow and so on, even the rule which years have a February with 29 days to handle the `yyyy0228235959` case, but why don't you use `date` for this task? It knows how to add a second.

Comment: GNU/awk does have complete general date processing (functions mktime, systime, strftime), although as there are no structs, the intermediate time representation is a string, which can be clunky to use. However, if you have a large input file, awk time avoids the overhead of calling an external process for every line. In particular, it will renormalise the whole date if any field is out of range (positive or negative), so (e.g.) you can just subtract 400 from the `dd` field.

Comment: In certain edge cases there are 61 seconds in a minute, so you cannot uniformly switch from 59 to 00

Comment: @roaima what cases are those? Some weird thing like [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333) something more common?

Comment: @terdon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second - note the last leap second was added in December 2016 and the intention is to have none after 2035, so it really isn't a common occurrence

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With GNU `awk` or [@ThomasDickey's `mawk`](https://www.invisible-island.net/mawk/)¹:

```bash
$ gawk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{
   gsub("..", "& ", $7)
   sub(" ", "", $7)
   $7 = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", mktime($7) + 1)
   print}' < your-file
09099458|1|000|41181|0|0|20221130164739|67
82060649|1|000|36827|0|0|20221130172400|67
```

The `gsub()` call turns `"20221130164739"` into `"20 22 11 30 16 47 39 "`, `sub()` removes the first space to get `"2022 11 30 16 47 39 "` the format expected by `mktime()`. The latter converts that to the UNIX epoch time. We add 1 to that and reformat as YYYYmmddHHMMSS.

If your `awk` doesn't support `mktime()` / `strftime()`, you can always use `perl` and its core `Time::Piece` module instead:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -F'\|' -lase '
  $F[6] = (Time::Piece->strptime($F[6], $format) + 1) -> strftime($format);
  print join "|", @F' -- -format=%Y%m%d%H%M%S < your-file
```

Here, we rely on `Time::Piece`'s `strptime()` similar to standard C function by the same name to parse the input string into a date. That makes that solution more easily adaptable to other date formats (in addition to being more portable).

If you have neither `gawk`, `mawk` nor `perl`, some shells such as zsh or ksh93 have builtin support for date/time parsing and formatting.

For instance, in `zsh`, that could be:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
format=%Y%m%d%H%M%S
while IFS='|' read -ru3 -A fields; do
  strftime -rs t $format $fields[7] &&
    strftime -s 'fields[7]' $format $(( t + 1 ))
  print -r -- ${(j[|])fields}
done 3< your-file
```

---

<sup>¹ Since [the 20121129 version](https://www.invisible-island.net/mawk/CHANGES.html#t20121129) released almost exactly 10 years ago as of writing.</sup>